# html select repeated values 'valid'?

Tags: html, dom, frameworks

Is a select with repeated values “well formed” or “valid”? I’ve been looking for references to this with no luck. The reason i’m asking is a lot of frameworks give the syntax

```
-createSelect(array options, array selected, type, etc)-
```

and this options array is an associative array, implying there are not repeated values. But this https://jsfiddle.net/uqkzvd9s/ does not trigger any warning in the browser that i can see.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is no restriction in HTML that limits the number of times a particular value can be used in a single select element.

Comment: thx for your answer Quentin. So, why are frameworks and models limiting the select if the standard does not?

Comment: Their own convenience.